# how to create a stack in fuerte?

Tags: ros, stack, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I would like to create a stack and am currently using ros fuerte. Since roscreate-stack is no longer supported, I would like to forward these questions from the ros-release mailing list here:

> The Fuerte migration page says roscreate-stack is no longer supported.
> Maintaining stack.xml dependencies by hand is tedious and error-prone.
>
> What scripts or tools are available to facilitate those dependency calculations?
>
> As more ROS stacks resemble system
> dependencies, the developer is now
> responsible for knowing what system
> dependencies their code use and
> properly declare them. With more ROS
> stacks installing as system
> dependencies, more and more dependency
> information will be hidden within
> CMake declarations. For example, you
> can now compile against common_msgs
> without declaring any  tags.
> Thus, a roscreate-stack-like tool is
> essentially unmaintainable in the
> future, unless it attempted to parse
> build files.

What are the steps to properly create a stack in fuerte?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60409/how-to-create-a-stack-in-fuerte?/) by [whiterose](https://answers.ros.org/users/349/whiterose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2013-04-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Simply create a directory named like your stack, put a [stack.xml](http://ros.org/wiki/Stack%20Manifest) file in it and create packages as subdirectories of you stack dir.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [whiterose](https://answers.ros.org/users/349/whiterose/) on 2013-04-13**:
Thanks, I needed to be sure of that :). And I suppose that 'make'-ing the stack is simply through 'rosmake *'?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-04-14**:
You can simply run `rosmake stack-name` once you've created the stack.xml file.